# How do I redirect from Apache to Tomcat?

Tags: apache, url, tomcat, ports

I'm working on my first Java site. I'm running Apache Tomcat on port 8080, and Apache HTTPD on port 80. The current URL that I can access the site at is (for example) 123.4.5.6:8080. I want to **remove** the port number from the URL before I point the domain at the new IP.

At the moment I am only using Apache for phpmyadmin, however I plan on using it for CGI scripts and other stuff once I figure out `mod_jk` etc... So I don't want to change Tomcat's port to 80 and turn off Apache.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The correct way to do things is to leave Apache at 80 and Tomcat at 8080 and use a plug in (preferably mod_proxy) to proxy Tomcat from Apache. mod_proxy would only take you 10 minutes to set up.

This [how-to](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/proxy-howto.html) is very simple to follow.

Comment: I'd recommend this too - best not have your JVM running as root unless you've got some other way of allowing it to bind to port 80.

Comment: mod_jk allows you to not run as root and still use port 80 to serve requests through Apache.

Comment: @kgiannakakis: do you prefer this over mod_jk?

Comment: mod_proxy is a newer module and is considered to be better than mod_jk. It is only supported from Apache's version 2.2 onwards. I personally have only used mod_proxy.

Comment: This answer could benefit greatly if some of the key points of the how-to were included here. Curretly it is little more then a link-only answer.

Answer (score 18):

The usual way this is done, as you already mentioned, is to use `mod_jk` from Apache HTTPD to forward that content that you want to be processed by Tomcat.

There is a [Quick HowTo](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/quick.html) at tomcat.apache.org.  You need to do the following:

- Copy `mod_jk.so` into the appropriate modules directory for Apache HTTPD.
- Create a configuration file `workers.properties`
- In Apache HTTPD's `httpd.conf`, add a section to configure `mod_jk`.
- Ensure that Tomcat is configured to accept the `mod_jk` protocol, which is usually on port 8009.

The lines in `httpd.conf` with `JkMount`:

```
JkMount  /examples/* worker1
```

tell Apache HTTPD which requests are to be forwarded to Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

Both the helpful answers above are good, but I much prefer `mod_proxy` over `mod_jk`.  There's no extra installation to do for mod_proxy, unlike `mod_jk`, and the setup is much easier.  `mod_jk` gives you more control over detailed tuning of Tomcat parameters, but if you just want a simple redirect from Apache to Tomcat, `mod_proxy` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you want static content to be served by Apache instead of Tomcat you should use mod_jk : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

And what about SSL - if we want Apache to handle HTTPS, because it is faster then java/Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

you should configure your tomcat using this link. for tomcat 7
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html