# Tomcat fails on first request in combination with jsvc

Tags: apache, http, web-applications, tomcat, mod-proxy

I have a web application where the first request may take a few seconds as some singletons are initialised.

I've used the **mod_proxy** and **jsvc** construction mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603765) and described on [this page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/proxy-howto.html) to connect apache with tomcat (data is served via SSL)

For the sample Tomcat application, everything works as it should. However, when using my application I get the following error in my apache log:

```
[Wed Feb 10 09:48:29 2010] [error] [client 130.12.1.26] (70014)End of file found: proxy: error reading status line from remote server localhost
[Wed Feb 10 09:48:29 2010] [error] [client 130.12.1.26] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /MyWebApp/MyWebApp.faces
```

and I get the following error in my tomcat output:

```
10/02/2010 09:48:29 9947 jsvc.exec error: Service exit with a return value of 1
```

I'm not an expert on this so I would like to know what's the cause of the problem and where I should look for an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I used JFreeChart, which, for some reasons, tried to connect to the X session.

By setting the following value in /etc/init.d/tomcat , I managed to get around it:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"
```