# Tomcat deployment done. How to access website normally?

Tags: tomcat

I've managed to deploy my war file to Tomcat. However, I'm only able to access my website via foo.com:8080/SomeApp. What I'd like is to access my website normally e.g., foo.com should take me to my website automatically. This isn't happening though? How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have installed a `SomeApp.war`. If your webapp is supposed to be run in the root (meaning `/`) context, it should be named `ROOT.war`. However, if you just want a forward from `http://foo.com/` to `http://foo.com/SomeApp`, you can add a `index.html` in your Tomcat's `webapps` folder containing the meta header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/SomeApp" />
```

For port redirecting (80 -> 8080), it depends on your installation: Do you use an Apache HTTPD with your tomcat, then take a look at [How do I redirect from Apache to Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603765).