# Redirect Tomcat 7 80 to Apache 8080

Tags: java, php, apache, tomcat

I have a problem with my server, 
I know I can do Apache 80 to Tomcat 8080, but I need Tomcat 7 port 80 to Apache  port 8080.

this is possible?

now: www.my-java-web.com and www.my-php-web.com:8080

final: www.my-java-web.com and www.my-php-web.com

Edit: 
opposite like this [How do I redirect from Apache to Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603765/how-do-i-redirect-from-apache-to-tomcat)

Comment: I flagged this question because it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: i have one server with "tomcat 7 (java) port 80" and "apache (php) port 8080". 
I would like to redirect my website www.example.com (website on php) from my tomcat "port 80" (Java) to my Apache "port 8080".

Comment: why don't you just change so that your tomcat is configured to be on 80 and apache on 8080? for what do you use redirection for?

Comment: change apache port 80 and tomcat to 8080 ... It is my last option

Comment: why? you need to explain your intentions clearly so we can answer this

Comment: you could also just have a frontend apache, which could redirect to either tomcat or another apache instance

Comment: beacuse  tomcat application is on production and I can not stop long time

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% clear what you really want to do but I will try to achieve an answer for you which already works on my system:

> now: www.my-java-web.com and www.my-php-web.com:8080
>
> final: www.my-java-web.com and www.my-php-web.com

So you will have 2 different domain.
Still apache needs to run on 80 simply change that in the *apache2.conf* or *httpd.conf* by adding `LISTEN 80` because that will be the entry port.

You than can create a **VirtualHost** in the Apache which allows you to redirect the domain www.my-java-web.com directly to you java backend without and of course you then also need to change the tomcat port to another one than `80` because that's already in use by apache - no way to get rid of that task.

```
<VirtualHost *>
   ServerAdmin xx@example.com
   ServerName www.my-java-web.com
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   # setup the proxy
   <Proxy *>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:{your new tomcat port}/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:{your new tomcat port}/
</VirtualHost>
```