# Apache Redirect Request From Domain + Path

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I am using apache in front of tomcat so I can redirect requests from the domain to the tomcat url using mod_proxy. I've run into an issue on the server where when using a subdomain it wants to go back to the base domain. Is there any way to redirect all requests from example.com/foo to foo.example.com?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com/app
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyPass / http://app.example.com:8080/AppName/
ProxyPassReverse / http://app.example.com:8080/AppName/
</VirtualHost>
```

The example above is not working. I presume that is because I cannot include a path in the servername.

Here is my working version of the tag based on the accepted answer.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com/app
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyPass / http://app.example.com:8080/AppName/
ProxyPassReverse / http://app.example.com:8080/AppName/

# Rewrite all request from example.com/foo to foo.example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/foo/?(.*) http://foo.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking strictly to the last statement in your original post, "Is there any way to redirect all requests from example.com/foo to foo.example.com".

You can use a rewrite to accomplish this. For example:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/foo/?(.*) http://foo.example.com/$1 [R,L]

This assumes that your rewrite module is loaded and enabled:

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine On

Comment: I'm struggling with how to use rewrite because this isn't actually an apache site. Apache literally just sits in front and forwards the requests to a tomcat application url.

Comment: Scratch that. This worked. Instead of including the rewrite within an .htaccess (because I don't have one) I simply included it directly in the virtual host. I'm going to include the working virtualhost tag in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mod_rewrite within apache.  Ensure it is enabled, as root:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

That will confirm it is has been enabled or already is.  If it has been enabled you'll need a restart of Apache.

Then in your root of your virtualhost create/edit `.htaccess` file and add the line:

```
Redirect /foo/ http://foo.example.com/
```

Depending on your specific directory permissions you may need to allow overrides for the directory

```
<Directory /your/path/here>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

HTH

Comment: I don't actually have anything living inside apache. All i'm using apache for is to redirect to my tomcat app. Will this still work in that situation?

Comment: Also will this preserve the remaining parts of the path? example.com/foo/more to foo.example.com/more.

Comment: Hmm possibly not, sorry.  I am sure you could use Mod_rewrite to achieve your goals, although might be worth reading this post, may help with your problem better? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603765/how-do-i-redirect-from-apache-to-tomcat